# Why I cant encode some types of videos on azure media service?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-media-services

So I am trying to upload and encode file on azure media service. If the video format is MPEG-4 it uploads successfully, but if the format is MPEG-PS it fails.

**Error Code:**
ErrorExecutingTaskUnsupportedFormat

**Error Message:**
An error has occurred. Stage: AnalyzeInputMedia. Code: System.IO.InvalidDataException. System.IO.InvalidDataException: Failed to create MediaItem for blob-ea71728299ee44a5b9866e478292a2a0: Invalid data found when processing input!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mentioned exception is caused by the unsupported input file format. [The official docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/an-introduction-to-live-encoding-with-azure-media-services/) say only MPEG-TS is supported.

> The input protocols supported by Live Encoding are: RTMP, RTP (MPEG
> TS) and Smooth Streaming. You can send in a live feed where the video
> is encoded with MPEG-2 (up to 422 Profile), or H.264...

**The difference between MPEG-TS and MPEG-PS**

**MPEG-TS** - transport stream for communication and broadcasting app,

**MPEG-PS** - used for storage application (DVD).

Simply, Azure Media Services supports only MPEG-TS containers.